# How do I change where a variable is pointing to within a function?

Tags: python

I have a python function that takes an object and either modifies it or replaces it.

```
def maybe_replace_corgi(corgi):
  # If corgi is cute enough, modify it to keep it.
  if corgi.cuteness > threshold:
    corgi.will_keep = True
  else:
    # Corgi not cute enough! Instantiate new corgi.
    corgi = Corgi(name="Woofus")
```

I know that objects are passed into python functions by reference. But what if I want to replace an object within a function entirely? As I want to do in my else statement? How do I make all references to the corgi object in my program point to this new corgi object?

Comment: You can use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt) statement here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary only in very specific kinds of situations....

Comment: FWIW, ruby provides this behavior if its something you really need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way would be to return a new corgi or the old corgi:

```
def maybe_replace_corgi(corgi):
    if corgi.cuteness > threshold:
        corgi.will_keep = True
        return corgi
    else:
        return Corgi(name="Woofus")

my_corgi = Corgi(name="Rudolf")
my_corgi = maybe_replace_corgi(my_corgi)
```

The downside of this is, as mentioned by others: It doesn't replace all references, it only replaces that one reference of `my_corgi`. However, *replacing all references is not possible*.

---

Instead of replacing all references to your object, you could just edit your object to look just like a new one. Just replace all it's attributes' values. For this you could create a new method in `Corgi` class, which resets all attributes.

In most cases you don't need a *new* method, you already got one: If your `__init__` method doesn't do anything too fancy (fe. increase `Corgi.count` variable or such) it can be called again to re-init all of your object's attributes.

```
def maybe_replace_corgi(corgi):
    if corgi.cuteness > treshold:
        corgi.will_keep = true
    else:
        corgi.__init__(name="Woofus")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  The only things you can do are to mutate that object so it has the new value you want (as you do in the first part of your `if` statement), or return it, or store it somewhere that other code will look for it when it wants the value.

For instance, if you do your work in a class, and always set/access the corgi as `self.corgi`, then doing `self.corgi = Corgi(name="Woofus")` will work, since subsequent reads of `self.corgi` will read the new value.  A similar effect can be achieved by having the caller do `corgi = maybe_replace_corgi(corgi)`, and having `maybe_replace_corgi` return the old corgi or a new one.

In general you can't do things like "change all references everywhere in the program".  If you are judicious in not creating tons of references to the same object, and instead create only a limited number of references in particular contexts, then you will have no problem changing *those* references when the time comes.

Comment: The standard practice would be to have this function return the new corgi value to use, either the same one passed in or the replaced one.

Comment: @Dougal: Sure, but that won't "change all references" to that object.

Comment: Of course not, just pointing out how you'd usually handle that.